# jQuery Mobile checkbox dead after after 20 uses

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've got a jQuery Mobile (1.4.0) / Phonegap (3.3) app that is some kind of a multiple choice test. After the first question is answered, the next question gets answered and so on. There is some kind of weird behavior, because after 20 or 40 successful questions, the checkboxes are not checkable anymore. That behavior is not predictable, so sometimes everything works fine for very long, and the next time after 20 questions the checkboxes are dead. By now the problem can only be reproduced on Android devices.

My html-page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="testChapter">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1 class="test">Test</h1>
    </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">

                    <input id="checkbox0" type="checkbox">
                    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="answerId0">
                    <input type="hidden" value="false" id="correct0">
                    <label class="checkBoxLabel" for="checkbox0" id="answerText0">
                   answer 0
                    </label>

                    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
                    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="answerId1">
                    <input type="hidden" value="false" id="correct1">
                    <label class="checkBoxLabel" for="checkbox1" id="answerText1">
                   answer 1
                    </label>

                    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
                    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="answerId2">
                    <input type="hidden" value="false" id="correct2">
                    <label class="checkBoxLabel" for="checkbox2" id="answerText2">
                        answer 2
                    </label>


            </fieldset>
    <button class="ui-btn ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left next" id="testNext">next</button>  
   </div>
</div>
```

The nextButton gets bound to a function nextTestItem() that does for each of the 3 answers (index is between 0 and 2):

```
$('#answerId'+index).val(shuffledAnswers[index].id);
$('#correct'+index).val(shuffledAnswers[index].correct);
$('#answerText'+index).text(shuffledAnswers[index].answer);

$("#checkbox"+index).prop("checked", false);
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Anyone any idea, where the error could be? At some point the checkboxes are not checkable anymore...

Comment: try `$("#checkbox"+index).prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh")` only instead of `$("#checkbox"+index).prop("checked", false);
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio("refresh");`.

Comment: do ou stop the propagation of the clic event in your nextTestItem function?

Comment: @Omar: when I leave out the last 2 lines the checkboxes stay checked, I want to look unchecked.

Comment: it works with one line only. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Rrs5r/

Comment: @Omar: thank you! I had to add

`if (!$('#checkbox'+index).hasClass('ui-listview'))
        $('#checkbox'+index).checkboxradio();`

at the beginning of nextTestItem (otherwise there would have been an exception calling the testChapter page for the first time) and with your modification at the end, it seems to work - as the problem was not predictable, it's hard to say. But 80 tries are good start.